# fulfiling a merge request on GitLab

Tags: merge, request, gitlab, review

First I DO NOT HAVE ANY EXPERIENCE WITH GitLab!

Will someone please tell me how to fulfill the merge request on GitLab?
Like what are the steps required to do a merge request in GitLab?

I was sent an email indicating that I was added to a project on GitLab.
When I accessed the project on GitLab a merge request was assigned to me.

I am supposed to do the following:
 1. add comments to each line of code.
 2. changes the code to fix the errors.
 3  merge these changes to a master branch

I have looked for help but cant find clear documentation on the GitLab site.
All the video take for granted that the viewers already know how to perform a merge request in GitLab.
They are always focusing on some skill or feature on top of a merge request so they dont actually explain how to do a merge request in GitLab.

Will someone please tell me how to fulfill the merge request on GitLab?
Like what are the steps required to do a merge request in GitLab?

Comment: did you already see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/ and https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/gitlab_flow.html ?

Answer (score 0):

If you like the proposed changes you can accept the merge request. Otherwise comment on and/or fix things you dislike.

I suppose this could be getting into opinion-based territory as the "merge request steps/practices" are often determined by the project owner(s) but in general a merge request is just a place to visualize and collaborate on proposed changes. Here is a nice [overview of MRs in the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/) as you have maybe already read.

Technically the only "required step" to fulfill the merge request in GitLab is to click that big green merge button.